# TypeScript result type based on parameter type

Tags: typescript

In this code, type of `v1` is `BehaviorSubject<string | number>` and type of `v2` is `{}`.

I want that type of `v1` be `BehaviorSubject<string>` and type of `v2` be `{ a: number, b: number }`.

Is something like this possible with TypeScript type system?

```
interface Test
{
    prop: {
        (x: string | number): BehaviorSubject<typeof x>;
        (x: {}): typeof x;
    }
}

let test: Test;
let v1 = test.prop('');
let v2 = test.prop({ a: 1, b: 2 });
```

It may be with latest TypeScript 2.1 even using keyof or mapped types feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using generics for this?

```
interface Test
{
    prop: {
        <T extends string | number> (x: T): BehaviorSubject<T>;
        <T> (x: T): T;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution of @Paarth answeared my question. I just had to use:

```
<T extends string> (x: T): BehaviorSubject<string>;
<T extends number> (x: T): BehaviorSubject<number>;
```

So prop(1) have compatible type (number, instead of constants) with prop(2).

Now I want something like this:

```
interface Int
{
    a: MyType<number>;
    b: MyType<string>;
    c: MyType<{ x: number, y: number }>;
}
```

Using the same logic, where types of a, b and c be respectively `BehaviorSubject<number>, BehaviorSubject<string> and { x: number, y: number }`.

Is this possible?

Comment: You may want to post this as a new question for visibility